# How to show that $\langle r^2\cup D_8 \rangle =D_8?$ or How to prove that $\langle r^2,D_8 \rangle$ is non-abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Give an explicit example of an abelian subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ such that $\langle H,C_G(H) \rangle$ is not abelian

My attempt : I found the example take $H=\langle r^2 \rangle$ and $G= D_8$

$\langle H,C_G(H) \rangle=\langle r^2,D_8 \rangle= \langle r^2\cup D_8 \rangle$

**My confusion** : How to show that  $\langle r^2\cup D_8 \rangle =D_8?$  or How to prove that $\langle r^2,D_8 \rangle$ is non-abelian

Comment: I hope $r$ here means an rotation element in $D_{8}$. $r^2 \cup D_{8}$ is just $D_8$, and group generated by it is of course $D_8$.

Comment: @sansae Yes $ r $ denote the rotation

Comment: Note $\langle H,C_G(H)\rangle=HC_G(H)$ is (non)abelian iff $C_G(H)$ is.

Answer (score 4):

Here, r denotes rotation in $D_8$. if $X$ is an element of set $G$ then $X$ union $G$ is the same as $G$. Since, here $r^2$ is an element of $D_8$, so $r^2$ union $D_8$ is $D_8$ itself. Now, $D_8$ itself forms a Group. By Closure property,we can say The group generated by $D_8$,is same as $D_8$.
So, $\langle r^2 \cup D_8\rangle = D_8$

Comment: please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)